# How do I solve 'Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.' when type checking Javascript (NOT Typescript) using // @ts-check in vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

In the view.js file:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
...
export {
  canvas,
};
```

in the main.js file:

```
 import * as view from '../src/view.js';
 ...
 xPosition: view.canvas.width / 2,
```

gives me `'Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`. type checking error.

I don't know how to proceed, I have zero knowledge of typescript, and the program is written in javascript anyway. All the solutions I have read require using typescript, which is useless in this example.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this error?

EDIT if I add the following:

```
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

in my view.js file it fixes all the errors in my main.js... BUT, when I add `// @ts-check` on the view.js file that contains the above line I get:

```
Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCanvasElement'.
  Property 'height' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'.
```

EDIT 2

I seemed to have solved that with adding some brackets using the following line:

```
const canvas = /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */ (document.getElementById('canvas'));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not all HTML elements have a width, although the canvas does. You can solve the issue by narrowing the type from `HTMLElement` to `HTMLCanvasElement` (code example taken from [this TypeScript article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/01/embracing-typescript-strict-mode/)).

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('x');

if (isCanvas(canvas)) {
    const width = canvas.width;
}

function isCanvas(obj: HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLElement): obj is HTMLCanvasElement {
    return obj.tagName === 'CANVAS';
}
```

Or you can cheat with a type annotation:

```
const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('x');
const width = canvas.width;
```

In JavaScript you can use JSDoc comments to perform type assertions:

```
/**
 * @type {HTMLCanvasElement}
 */
const canvas = document.getElementById('x');
```

And, though I haven't tried it, you might get away with a ts-ignore comment even though it is a JavaScript file:

```
// @ts-ignore: I don't care that it might not be a HTML Canvas Element
const width = canvas.width;
```

Comment: Thanks! Using JSDoc seems the perfect solution, but it creates another error, I have updated my post, please have a look, cheers. I don't think JS can use type annotations? <HTMLCanvasElement> gives a syntax error.

Comment: I found this useful for getting an iFrame:
let element = document.getElementById('iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;

Comment: @Meanman - beware of that, because it isn't guaranteed to be an iframe, see https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/02/apply-typescript-types-honestly/